# Find how many times keyword is repeated in all nodes

Tags: 7

I have nodes for business listings which have title , body and other contact fields of the business. 
I want to do a research on all my content "10000 nodes" and find the most repeated words in the title and body fields of each node, so I can tag the content using the keywords found.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is this a one time action or does it have to run periodically? This functionality would require a lot of resources with that amount of nodes. And it is hard to get the logic right because you need to filter words like 'the' and 'a'. You'd probably get a bunch of useless keywords.

Comment: One time only. I can set separate server and copy my data to do this task

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

I wrote this code from the top of my head and haven't tested it so I'm not sure if it works. There also might be some errors in it so you probably need to do some debugging.

```
// Get the body and title of all nodes.
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_body', 'body', 'body.entity_type = "node" and body.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'));
$query->fields('body', array('body_value'));

$result = $query->execute();

$blacklist = array('the', 'a');

while ($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
  // Put the words in an array.
  $title_words = explode(' ', strtolower($record->title));
  // Count the same words.
  $title_word_count = array_count_values($title_words);
  // Sort the array.
  asort($title_word_count);

  /* Do the same for $record->body_values and merge this array with $title_word_count. */

  // Filter blacklist elements.
  foreach ($blacklist as $blacklist_word) {
    if (isset($word_count[$blacklist_word])) {
      unset($word_count[$blacklist_word]);
    }
  }

  if (!empty($word_count)) {
    // The last element of the array contains the most frequent word.
    $word = array_pop($title_word_count);

    /* Here you can insert this word as a taxonomy term and add it to the node. */
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want Solr installed which provides such thing out of box.

1. Install and configure [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) + [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).
2. Create Solr server and indexes, so all nodes are indexed.

Now Solr server can give you such information, as you can either log-in to your Solr web interface and execute specific query to fetch the statistics or use Luce (Lucene Index Browser) which allows to show you such statistics.

---

Alternatively you can use SQL or shell command.

For example:

```
drush sqlq "SELECT title, COALESCE(r.body_value, '') FROM node n LEFT JOIN field_data_body r ON n.nid = r.entity_id AND n.vid = r.revision_id" | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' | grep -o "\w\+" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n20
```

will print top 20 most used words from all the nodes. For specific nodes or type, use `WHERE` to narrow down the results.

Comment: Dont have solr installed on my server. I will try with sql group and count

Comment: @AbdullahAlsagr I've included SQL query with some Linux commands to sort and do the stats.